# Google Chrome Installation Not working Properly 20.04

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

I'm currently running 20.04 but had this same issue with 18.04. When I install the `.deb` package provided by the main link from google I get a successful installation, but I get no icon, and I am unable to launch chrome from the terminal using the `google-chrome-stable` command.

All research seems to indicate I should get an icon to simply click on and run chrome, most other issues related to similar symptoms are several years old at this point.

Installation happens as `sudo`. The installation has been attempted with `dpkg` command as well as `apt install google-chrome-stable`. Both complete seeming without error.

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you how I'm installing Chrome on all of the distros, most importantly for you, on Ubuntu 20.04; and hopefully it'll be useful to you.

Usually, I go directly to Chrome download link. When the installer (.deb) is downloaded, I just go double click on the file and it's usually taken care of. I understand why would you use terminal, but in this particular case, I recommend downloading .deb installer directly from the Google Chrome website, instead of using ubuntu software, snap store or terminal.